# PHP mb_detect_encoding no longer reliably detects UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, mbstring

I recently switched from PHP 7 to PHP 8.2.7 and noticed that mb_detect_encoding seems to no longer work reliably. I am doing the following:

```
mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents('somefile.csv'), 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true);
```

For one particular file, the value returned is ISO-8859-1, even though it clearly is a UTF-8 encoded file. It even has a UTF-8 BOM. I understand that the detection algorithm changed in PHP 8, but how can a clear UTF-8 encoded file be mistaken for ISO? I get that most UTF-8 encoded strings are also valid ISO strings, but what good is mb_detect_encoding if it fails to see the difference? BTW. the file in question is 1759 Bytes long and has around 30 UTF-8 two-byte characters, so IMO this should be plenty to detect it as UTF-8.

I cannot upload files, but this is the first line of the .CSV file:

```
Buchungstag;Wertstellung;Umsatzart;Buchungstext;Betrag;Währung;Auftraggeberkonto;Bankleitzahl Auftraggeberkonto;IBAN Auftraggeberkonto
```

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` is a poorly named function that has never done what people think. If it reports ISO-8859-1, it just means that there's a byte sequence that is not valid UTF-8.

Comment: How about sharing the file so that everybody can take a look at it?

Comment: I can't give you an answer to "what good is mb_detect_encoding if it fails to see the difference", but I can tell you that per [this](https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/8279), the order is no longer honored as authoritative, and instead "heuristics" are also applied. This means that the documentation is no longer correct, and there's an [issue](https://github.com/php/doc-en/issues/1708) and [PR](https://github.com/php/doc-en/pull/2426) for updating the docs. The recommended fix for you is to use `mb_check_encoding` in a loop. Not ideal, but that's where it appears to be.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UTF-8 BOM. The byte order is fixed in UTF-8. The BOM is only relevant for UTF-16 and -32. In UTF-8, U+FEFF encodes a zero-width space. Probably not what is intended here.

Comment: "There is no such thing as a UTF-8 BOM" - There is a BOM for UTF-8, but it doesn't imply any order to the bytes. Some systems (notably older Windows) use it to imply that the stream of text is explicitly meant to be interpreted as UTF-8. If you just mean that a BOM isn't needed for UTF-8, that's something different.

Comment: There is a BOM in UTF-8  (byte sequence EF BB BF). The BOM is not required but permitted in UTF-8. At least for Microsoft Excel, it signals that a .CSV file is encoded in UTF-8. If it is not present, Excel will interpret the encoding as CP1252 or something and will not correctly interpret UTF-8 encoded characters.

Answer (score 0):

I still feel that mb_detect_encoding is broken, but at least I found that is is the Byte-order-mark EF BB BF at the beginning of the file that appears to throw it off. If it is present and the rest of the file is too short (< about 4K), it appears to be detected as ISO-8859-1.

One workaround is to strip off a potential BOM first:

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding(preg_replace("/^\xef\xbb\xbf/", '', file_get_contents('somefile.csv')), 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true);
```

or to use mb_check_encoding:

```
$encoding = mb_check_encoding(file_get_contents('somefile.csv'), 'UTF-8') ? 'UTF-8' : 'ISO-8859-1';
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to assume UTF-8 if the BOM appears? I thought it was a pretty reliable signal

Comment: Right, of course. Sometimes the most obivious solution just eludes you. Thanks.